# Intellisense Xamarin Forms does not work - Visual Studio Enterprise with Update 3

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms, intellisense

I installed VS with Xamarin but Intellisense in XAML files is not working properly. In some parts of the code it shows the list of suggestions as shown below.

[image]

Except in other parts of the code it does not show the list with all the items (image below).

[image]

It is also opening the XAML with the XML Editor, but should it not be with XAML Designer?

Does anyone have any suggestions for resolving or circumventing this problem?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 behaviors that you described are by design, you can look at the following screenshot, since you type “<” inside and outside the node , the auto complete member list is different which defined in the XML Schemas. 
[image]
For the second question, Xamarin.Forms doesn't currently support visual designers for XAML files. There is not yet a visual designer for generating XAML in Xamarin.Forms applications, so all XAML must be hand-written. We can know this from [Why doesn't the Visual Studio XAML designer work for Xamarin.Forms XAML files?](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms-xaml-designer/), but we can try to use the [XAML Previewer for Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/) to help us to preview the UI.